# Prevent MVC Form to clear form values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, postback

So my problem is simple. After submitting my form all form-values are removed.

Looking at questions asked here at Stackoverflow makes me think most people have the opposite problem, which is the default behavior?

Anyway my view is simple

```razor
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Default"))
{
  <input type="text" name ="FirstName" />
  <input type="text" name="LastName" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

And here is the controller.

```
 public class DefaultController : Controller
 {
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new FormViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

My ViewModel

```
public class FormViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

After submitting my input fields are empty. How do i keep values in the input fields? (in real life I have a much bigger form of course)

Comment: use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Still same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HtmlHelpers text box

```
Html.TextBox("FirstName", Model.FirstName, new {
    @class = "form-control",
    PlaceHolder = "FirstName"
})
```

Create a model to grab the data into the controller and also pass the model while rendering view

Answer (score 0):

Whan calling the view again, forward the data again, same as first time. Return View(data); where data is of some type (preferably ViewModel) and that is populated with posted form data (expected from data binding).

this is classic:

```
    public ActionResult New ()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult New (NewPlaceVM vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && vm != null)
        {
            var model = Mapper.Map<NewPlaceVM, Place>(vm);
            _place.New(model);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(vm);
    }
```

And in View use EditorFor or any other HTML helper that suits best

```
@model NewPlaceVM

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ignore, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ignore, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ignore, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-right">
                <input type="submit" value="@Ress.Ress.Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: @Tushar Gupta I didn't see the View problem

Comment: Adding the @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName); helped. I was hoping i didn't have too do that but there seem to be no way around.

Comment: you can do <input type="text" name="SomeName" value="@Model.Property" /> it will do the sam thing, but using HTML helpers is smarter

Answer (score 0):

```
I have prevented form clearing for search form for my website mrnams.com

View
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-right pull-right" }))
        {
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="input-searchQuery" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this site" name="q">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        }

jQuery functions in View 

@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function ()
        {
            var queryReturned = '@ViewBag.SearchQuery';
            $("#input-searchQuery").val(queryReturned); 
        });
 

</script>
}
 
And here is the controller. 

public class Home : Controller
        {            
public ActionResult Search(string q)
            {
                ViewBag.SearchQuery = q;
}
}
```

For demo visit
https://mrnams.com/